# how to bind multiple key to a command in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In sublime, for example,I want to bind both `ctrl+1` and `ctrl+2` to a command, is there any way to set this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply repeat the config. For example:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+ctrl+f"], "command": "toggle_full_screen" },
    { "keys": ["super+alt+f"], "command": "toggle_full_screen" }
]
```

Will result in both `super+ctrl+f` and `super+alt+f` working.

*Note the `,` at the end of the lines except the last line if you're getting syntax errors.*

---

Don't confuse it with using a pair of shortcuts for a single command, which is done like this:

```
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+b"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" },
```